# Why I get an error when I run an e2e test using protractor with waitForAngularEnabled(true)

Tags: angular, protractor, angular9

I'm using protractor for e2e testing my angular app. For the login page I set waitForAngularEnabled(false) and afterwards I set it to waitForAngularEnabled(true). But my tests are failing with this error:

```
 Failed: script timeout
          (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.83)
          (Driver info: chromedriver=85.0.4183.38 (9047dbc2c693f044042bbec5c91401c708c7c26a-refs/branch-heads/4183@{#779}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18362 x86_64)
          (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.83)
          (Driver info: chromedriver=85.0.4183.38 (9047dbc2c693f044042bbec5c91401c708c7c26a-refs/branch-heads/4183@{#779}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18362 x86_64)
            at Object.checkLegacyResponse (....node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
            at parseHttpResponse (....node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
            at doSend.then.response (....node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)
            at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
        From: Task: Protractor.waitForAngular() - Locator: By(css selector, body)
```

When I google for it I find a lot of posts suggesting I should set synchronization off or set waitForAngularEnabled to false. But then I loose this functionality.

Someone has an idea how to fix this?

Comment: can you add your code when you set it back to `true`

Answer (score 0):

I found out thanks to this post (https://christianliebel.com/2016/11/angular-2-protractor-timeout-heres-fix/) that it was caused by timeouts which are used in the app. I replaced them with the proposed solution and now it works like a charm.

So for this to work you search for setInterval and setTimeout and replace them with:

```
ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
        ngZone.run(() => {
            // async operation
        });
    }, 2500);
```